# Como alterar o nome da coluna do dataframe do pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Estou usando o pandas para processar um arquivo CSV na seguinte estrutura:

```
nome;idade
Fulano;28
Joao da Silva;27
Maria;29
```

A leitura do arquivo é feita da seguinte forma:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dados.csv', sep=';')
```

É gerado meu dataframe `df` com o conteúdo do CSV:

```
            nome  idade
0         Fulano     28
1  Joao da Silva     27
2          Maria     29
```

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber como eu posso alterar o nome das colunas no meu dataframe? Tentei usar a função `rename` desta forma:

```
df.rename(columns={'nome': 'nome_completo'})
```

mas, aparentemente não funcionou.

Gostaria de trocar o nome da coluna `nome` para `nome_completo` no dataframe.

Comment: Gato, se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema, você poderia marcar uma delas como aceita. Entenda importância disso nesse link: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) do comando `rename`, o retorno dessa função é um novo DataFrame com a(s) coluna(s) renomeada(s). 
 Para você chegar na resposta desejada, (1) basta atribuir o retorno da função em uma nova variável, ou (2) passar o comando `inplace = True` que ele atribuirá o novo nome da coluna direto no DataFrame que você possui.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'nome': 'nome_completo'})
#ou
df.rename(columns={'nome': 'nome_completo'}, inplace = True)
```

---

Também é possível mudar o nome das colunas passando apenas um dicionário para a função `.rename()` junto com o parametro **axis=1**, desta forma:

```
df = df.rename({'nome': 'nome_completo'}, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode passar uma lista com os novos nomes que você deseja:

```
df.columns = ['nome_completo', 'idade']
```

Apenas um adendo, o comando `df.rename(columns = {'nome':'nome_completo'})` está correto, mas para que a alteração seja implementada no `df` você precisa adicionar o argumento `inplace = True`.

Answer (score 3):

Tente assim

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dados.csv', sep=';', names=['nome_completo', 'idade'], header=0)
```

dependendo do seu arquivo csv, talvez seja necessário atribuir `header=1` para omitir o cabeçalho anterior

assim não precisará adicionar mais nenhuma outra linha

Comment: Boa Guilherme, mas lembre que o `header` tem que ser `0` ;)

Comment: depende do seu arquivo csv, como não possuo não pude fazer o teste para verificar a forma mais correta para o seu problema, mas é um jeito de de alcançar seu objetivo sendo necessário adaptar de acordo com a sua saída esperada, mas se acha que ficaria melhor a reposta com __header=0__, posso deixa do jeito que melhor resolveu o seu problema

Answer (score 3):

Você pode nomear as colunas assim que chamar a função `read_csv` do pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dados.csv', delimiter=';', encoding='iso-8859-1', usecols=['nome_completo', 'idade'])
```

além de nomear, pode adicionar parâmetros extras como delimitador e encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu apenas de colocar Unique = True no final.

df.rename(columns={'nome': 'nome_completo'}, Unique = True)

Prontinho, dessa forma irá funcionar!!

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar também:

```
df.rename({"nome": "nome_completo"}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```